# Ansible: extracting a dictionary from a complex JSON data structure

Tags: json, ansible, yaml

```
{
"vmware_dc": {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "All items completed",
    "results": [
        {
            "ansible_loop_var": "item",
            "changed": false,
            "datacenter_info": [
                {
                    "config_status": "gray",
                    "moid": "datacenter-1146",
                    "name": "dc-1",
                    "overall_status": "gray"
                }
            ],
            "failed": false,
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "datacenter": null,
                    "hostname": "vc-001",
                    "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                    "port": 443,
                    "properties": null,
                    "proxy_host": null,
                    "proxy_port": null,
                    "schema": "summary",
                    "show_tag": false,
                    "username": "",
                    "validate_certs": false
                }
            },
            "item": "vc-001"
        },
        {
            "ansible_loop_var": "item",
            "changed": false,
            "datacenter_info": [
                {
                    "config_status": "gray",
                    "moid": "datacenter-424",
                    "name": "dc-2",
                    "overall_status": "gray"
                },
                {
                    "config_status": "gray",
                    "moid": "datacenter-2",
                    "name": "dc-3",
                    "overall_status": "gray"
                }
            ],
            "failed": false,
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "datacenter": null,
                    "hostname": "vc-002",
                    "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                    "port": 443,
                    "properties": null,
                    "proxy_host": null,
                    "proxy_port": null,
                    "schema": "summary",
                    "show_tag": false,
                    "username": "",
                    "validate_certs": false
                }
            },
            "item": "vc-002"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Please see JSON results above. I hope that someone can help me. I should take two fields, an item and datacenter_info.name
I can get values separate. I don't know how to create a dictionary because I have 2 items and 3 datacenter_info.name

```
enter - name: Set all_items
  set_fact:
    all_items: "{{ vmware_dc_info.results | flatten | map(attribute='item) | flatten }}"

- name: debug all_items
  debug:
    var: all_items

    {
"all_items": [
    "vc-001",
    "vc-002"
]

- name: Set all dc
  set_fact:
    all_dc: "{{ vmware_dc_info.results | flatten | map(attribute='datacenter_info') | flatten | map(attribute='name') | flatten }}"

- name: debug all_dc
  debug:
    var: all_dc
    


"all_dc": [
    "dc-1",
    "dc-2",
    "dc-3"
```

Dictionary should looks like below

```
vc-001: dc-1
vc-002: dc-2
vc-002: dc-3
```

Is it possible?  What do you think?

Resolved with code below

```
    - name: Set fact
  set_fact:
    dc_list: "{{ dc_list | default([]) + [{'vcenter':  item[0].item, 'dc': item[1].name}] }}"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ vmware_dc_info.results }}"
    - datacenter_info
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item[0].item }}"

- name: Debug
  debug:
    var: dc_list
```

Answer (score 0):

For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        hostnames: "{{ hostnames|d({})|combine({item: names}) }}"
      loop: "{{ vmware_dc.results|map(attribute='item')|list }}"
      vars:
        _item: "{{ vmware_dc.results|selectattr('item', '==', item) }}"
        names: "{{ _item.0.datacenter_info|map(attribute='name')|list }}"
```

gives you the expected result

```yaml
hostnames:
  vc-001:
    - dc-1
  vc-002:
    - dc-2
    - dc-3
```

Comment: fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'str object' has no attribute 'datacenter_info

Comment: Something wrong  with names var